# Change Jackson SpringBoot default to serialize LocalDateTime object

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-webflux, localdatetime

I'm trying to change the default serialization of SpringBoot so that it can handle a LocalDateTime object.  This works fine for POJOs that I have annotated with

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
 @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
 private LocalDateTime date;
```

But I have an application using WebFlux where a Map is passed as an argument and it's not getting serialized properly.
The code looks something like this, where `contract` is a Map<String, Object>, and one of the entries in the Map has a type of LocalDateTime

```
webClient.post()
.uri(url.toString())
.header("Authorization", authToken)
.body(Mono.just(contract), contract.getClass())
.retrieve()
.bodyToMono(Response.class)
```

I was able to create an ObjectMapper with

```
public static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
```

and then using `mapper.writeValueAsString(contract)`, worked correctly, outputting the date as "2021-06-29T12:46:36".  I already have jackson-datatype-jsr310 in my POM.

But I can't get this to work with WebFlux

Tried defining a bean

```
 @Bean
 @Primary
 public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
   final JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
   final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.registerModule(module);
   mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
   return mapper;
 }
```

If I inject Spring's ObjectMapper into my code, along with the bean, then it works if I do `mapper.writeValueAsString(contract)`.  So this at least proves that Spring's ObjectMapper is changed.   But when I send the map through the WebClient, the server is getting the date in this format: `date=[2021, 6, 23, 20, 48, 50]`

Comment: What version of Spring Boot? In the latest version, no Jackson annotation is required and the auto-configured ObjectMapper well serializes and deserializes Java 8 date time.

Comment: Try to set two properties:
`spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` and 
`spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false` in your `Spring` properties file

Comment: We're using 2.45 of SpringBoot.  I have not found that LocalDateTime is serialized correctly.  It serialized the individual fields, e.g., month, day, year, etc, into separate fields.  Not as a single string.